# Google Plugin for Eclipse not use last version of libraries

Tags: eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I am using **Google Plugin for Eclipse** and [I add API from this plugin](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/googleapis) ("Plugin>Add Google APIs...").

I would like to know why it is not using the last versions of some libraries. For example, if I add Drive API from this plugin, it is not using last version of google-api-client (plugin is using 1.16 and release 1.18 is available).

I use the last version of Google Plugin for Eclipse.

Is it normal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Google Plugin for Eclipse. For now, you can, of course, download the latest version of the API from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/.

(BTW, are you sure GPE used version 1.16 and not version 1.12?)

Comment: Hi, I use GPE 4.2 and it downloads 1.16 libraries from these plugins